# IIS app pool crashes when another WCF application is added to IIS in windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, wcf, signalr, signalr-hub, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two applications running smoothly on a windows server without issues.
A windows .exe application and ASP.NET application. For years it has been running fine, but recently we decided to add a new WCF application in the server which will run separately as a standalone application but have access to a separate .dll fills of the already running ASP.NET application.

The windows .exe application receives json messages through a port from a specified IP address and then broadcast those messages to the connected ASP.NET application through a port by using signalR.

The Two applications work properly when they both are only running on the enterprise server but after the new WCF application is added in the server as a standalone server, the ASP.NET web application pool crashes and is very difficult to restart again.

In addition, the wcf application also connects to the same socket as the ASP.NET application when receiving messages from the windows application

Whenever I remove or stop the WCF application after a restart of the server ASP.NET application starts working again.  But we need the WCF application as well in the server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can compare the differences between the two environments to see where the configurations are different.

Then according to your description, the problem may be related to the opening and closing of the wcf connection. After the application starts and opens the agent, if it is interrupted suddenly, the client will have an error, and the server that previously communicated no longer exists. When the client is restarted, the new proxy is connected. To solve this problem, you need to close wcf after it is connected. The application crash may also be related to too many connections.

If possible, you may share more detailed logs, which is more conducive to locating problems. Feel free to contact me if have any issues.

Comment: The two applications are also installed on some other servers and the same problem happens whenever this WCF application is installed on the server.

Comment: If possible, could you give some error logs for further analysis?